# Exception in compiled script

Tags: automation, autohotkey

I'd like to share an issue that the function `Exception(Message [, What, Extra])` doesn't work as expected if the script is compiled in .exe

- `Exception("").What` give the current method/function/subroutine if the script is not compiled
- `Exception("", -2).What` give the parent method where the method/function/subroutine has been called if the script is not compiled
- `Excetpion("").What` give the current method/function/subroutine if the script is compiled .exe
- `Exception("", -2).What` give only -2 if the script is compiled .exe

> ```
> class MyClass
> {
>     Method1() 
>     {
>          MsgBox % MyClass.Method2()
>     }
>
>     Method2()
>     {
>          return Exception("", -2).What
>     }
> }
>
> MyClass.Method1()
> ```

In non compiled `MyClass.Method1()` display MyClass.Method1

But in compiled .exe script `MyClass.Method1()` display -2

Anyone has a solution to display the method instead the number if the script is compiled?

Answer (score 1):

It actually does work as expected, as this behavior is stated in the [documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Throw.htm#Exception):

> If *What* is omitted, it defaults to the name of the current function or subroutine. Otherwise it can be a string or a negative offset from the top of the call stack. For example, a value of -1 sets `Exception.What` to the current function or subroutine, and `Exception.Line` and `Exception.File` to the line and file which called it. **However, if the script is [compiled](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#ahk2exe) or the offset is invalid, *What* is simply converted to a string.**

Also, I think your implementation here is a bit weird, surely you'd want to throw exceptions instead of returning them?

Anyway, I guess your solution would be to somehow implement this yourself.
You could for example pass the caller in as an argument:

```
instance := new MyClass

try
    instance.Method1()
catch e
    MsgBox, % e.What


class MyClass
{
    Method1() 
    {
        this.Method2(A_ThisFunc)
    }

    Method2(caller)
    {
        throw Exception("", caller)
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't expect to add A_ThisFunc

Comment: You asked for a workaround, I presented one. What is it exactly that you're looking to do then?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible the same behavior as if the script not compiled, because it return only -2 if the script is compiled. But I can't add A_ThisFunc everytime.

Comment: Seems like to me that your solution is to implement it yourself. Either by some deep magic, which I wouldn't know of, or then implement your own tracking of the when what was called etc.